# Problem with a function related to an GitHub API username search

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm unable to get this function operational. Everything else in the script is working just fine according to console.log. This is an API for GitHub username search.

I appreciate any help.

```
`<!-- language: lang-js -->
function showResults() {
      console.log('working');
      if (responseJson.message === "Unable To Locate Username") {
        $('.show-results hidden').append(`<h2>Sorry, We were unable to locate that username</h2>`);
    } else {
        $('.show-results hidden').append(`<h2>Here is your search results for ${wordData}</h2>
        <div id="${responseJson.message}" class="display-info">`);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Steezy! I recommend checking out `fenced code blocks` here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You've got bad syntax. You should not be using an acute/backtick `` ` ``, rather, you should be using a single quote `'`. You have a newline/CLRF in the middle of your append(), and you're also missing a closing brace.

```js
function showResults() {

    console.log('working');

    if (responseJson.message === "Unable To Locate Username") {
        $('.show-results hidden').append('<h2>Sorry, We were unable to locate that username</h2>');
    } else {
        $('.show-results hidden').append('<h2>Here is your search results for'+wordData+'</h2><div id="'+responseJson.message+'" class="display-info">');
    }

}
```